# Regex to find all substrings within % PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all the substrings within "%" in a string, but I dont understand why it only finds the "id".

```
$test = '<img src="%get_love%" alt="%f_id%" title="%id%" />';
$token_regex_inside_tags = "/<([^>]*%([\w]+)%[^>]*)>/";
preg_match_all($token_regex_inside_tags, $test, $matches);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assumption** :- *I am assuming that you need to find content within `%` only if its in between `<>`*.

You can use this regex which uses **[`\G`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G)**

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|<)[^%>]*%([^%>]*)%
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY0sB3/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?:
  \G(?!\A) #End of previous match
    | #Alternation
   < #Match < literally
)
[^%>]* #Find anything that's not % or >
%([^%>]*)% #Find the content within %
```

In your regex

```
< #Matches < literally
 (
   [^>]* #Moves till > is found. Here its in end
   %([\w]+)% #This part backtracks from last but is just able to find only the last content within two %
   [^>]*
)>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!